# Can I center a NSToolbarItem in a toolbar?

Tags: cocoa, macos

Its just that. I want to center two buttons. 
My toolbar looks like this ([B] is a button) :

> [B] <---- flexible space ---> [B][B]  <---- flexible space --->
>   [SearchBar]

But the search bar is bigger than the button on the far left so the middle buttons are not centered. I tried adding a view with a custom width but that is screwed up by localization.
Is there a way to center them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Centering things, or indeed controlling layout beyond button order, while possible using toolbars, is not necessarily a good idea.

**Edit:** It has been brought to my attention that Mail.app does indeed use Voodoo to do something quite like what you are suggesting.

They do this by keeping track of the toolbar items and resize the first flexible space in the toolbar to align the toolbar.

This might work for certain use cases, but is likely to be fragile; use with caution, and do keep in mind that if users can customize the toolbar, they are liable to remove the flexible space, mucking up your centering.

Comment: But Mail.app does that. They align the buttons with the source list?!

Comment: @david: Mail.app uses what can only be described as Voodoo.

Comment: Although this question is dated, this will replicate the same behavior as mail.app https://github.com/jwells89/JWToolbarAdaptiveSpaceItem

Comment: Hi @Cory , this JWToolbarAdaptiveSpaceItem is still not as fancy as the Voodoo one by Apple. The interesting feature of the Apple one is, in the "Customize Toolbar" mode, the toolbar item is animated when a new neighbour is added. The `NSToolbarFlexibleSpaceItem` has this behaviour, but it doesn't take into account the position of some other view, e.g. a subview of a splitview. There's no public `NSToolbarFlexibleSpaceItem` so it seems impossible to subclass it. I'll look into this problem later. Maybe some Core Animation is needed? Thanks for your very helpful comment!

Answer (score 13):

If your deployment target is macOS 10.14 (Mojave) or later, you can center a toolbar item by setting the toolbar's [`centeredItemIdentifier` property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstoolbar/2967178-centereditemidentifier?language=objc) to the identifier of the item you want centered.

This is intended for centering the toolbar item that contains the window title when you have set the window's `titleVisibility` to `NSWindowTitleHidden`. It might not work as well in other scenarios.

Answer (score 11):

A very belated response but since I also needed to do this i've just written a subclass that will create a space to center the next toolbar item:

http://github.com/timothyarmes/TAAdaptiveSpaceItem

Comment: Just what I need! Unfortunately, I can’t find a license on your code, other than Xcode’s default “all rights reserved”. Guessing that you intend for people to be able to use this, could you consider committing a BSD-style license file to the repo to make it official?

Comment: Yes, I need to add that. I'll add an MIT licence so you can assume that you may use it as you please...

Comment: Could you please add the license? This also solved my problem, but i can't use without the license. Thanks!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this complicated approach, I would let it center it by adding additional blank space items on each side till those two buttons are in the middle of the window. The toolbar should resize appropriately going forward.

Comment: That won't centre the item in the window, it'll only centre it between the items on either side. If there are more items on once side or the other it'll be off-cantered.